# Spin-$J$ Amplitude $A_J(s,t) = - \frac{g^2(-s)^J}{t-M^2}$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, angular-momentum, s-matrix-theory

In GSW equation (1.1.2) they define the scattering amplitude for a spin $J$ particle at high energies as
$$A_J(s,t) = - \frac{g^2(-s)^J}{t-M^2}$$
mentioning it is an asymptotic approximation to a formula involving Legendre polynomials, and in [this stackexchange post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/15164/25851) it is also defined, and in Williams 'Intro to Elementary Particles' book it is referred to as (proportional to) the Born contribution to the amplitude (section 12.9). It is also discussed from a string perspective in [Tong's string theory notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string.html) [eq. 6.13](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string/six.pdf). Are there any references for where this formula is derived/explained/discussed in a QFT context, where it comes from, for example the general formula in terms of Legendre polynomials and how it reduces to the above form?

Comment: possible dup.? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47504/84967

Answer (score 7):

The intuitive proof is straightforward. The group $SU(2)$ is simple, and so any representation is contained in the tensor product of sufficiently many copies of the fundamental ([à la Young](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Weyl_duality)). More specifically, a field of spin $j$ can be constructed by tensoring $2j$ copies of a spinor:
$$
\phi^{\alpha_1\cdots\alpha_{2j}}\sim\psi^{\alpha_1}\otimes\cdots\otimes\psi^{\alpha_{2j}}
$$
in the sense that the representation $j$ is a subspace of the representation $(1/2)^{\otimes 2j}$:
$$
\bigotimes^{2j} \frac12=j\oplus (j-1)\oplus\cdots
$$
from the standard rules of addition of angular momenta<sup>1</sup>. Thus, the propagator reads<sup>2</sup>
$$
\langle \phi^{\alpha_1\cdots\alpha_{2j}}\phi^{\alpha'_1\cdots\alpha'_{2j}}\rangle(p)=\frac{p^{\alpha_1\alpha'_1}\cdots p^{\alpha_{2j}}p^{\alpha'_{2j}}}{p^2-m^2}+\text{permutations}+\text{subleading}
$$

Here, the pole is fixed by unitarity (as in the standard proof of Källén-Lehman: this is the one-particle state contribution). The numerator is fixed by Lorentz invariance (here $p^{\alpha\alpha'}:=p^\mu\sigma^{\alpha\alpha'}_\mu$ is the standard map $SO(3)\to Spin(3)$). The "permutations" refers to the different ways to pair up the indices (which, in turns, is fixed by the symmetry properties of $\phi$, i.e., on the specific representation we are using), and "subleading" refers to terms where the Lorentz indices are provided by $\delta^{\alpha\alpha'}$ instead of momenta.

We thus see that 
$$
\Delta\sim \frac{p^{2j}}{p^2-m}=\frac{s^j}{s-m}
$$
modulo angle-dependent factors.

A more involved proof requires a careful analysis of the representation theory of $SU(2)$ and its invariant tensors (which specify the precise pairing of indices). One of the canonical references is Weinberg's [Phys. Rev. 133, B1318, 1964](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.133.B1318) and the follow up papers [Phys. Rev. 134, B882, 1964](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.134.B882), [Phys. Rev. 181, 1893](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.181.1893). The upshot is that the rough estimate above is in fact correct.

---

<sup>1: This refers to reps of $SU(2)$; a rep of Lorentz $SU(2)^2$ is obtained by taking pairs of reps, which leads to lower and upper indices. This is irrelevant for the discussion herein.</sup>

<sup>2: I do not pay attention to the overall sign here; it is fixed by unitarity: the residue is essentially a norm $|\langle 0|\phi|p\rangle|^2$, and so should be positive for $p$ on-shell. Again, refer to Källén-Lehman for a more detailed discussion.</sup>

Comment: In the first term of the third equation, is a factor of some analytic function of $p^2/m^2$ forbidden for some reason? It would neither break Lorentz invariance, nor change the position of the pole.

Comment: Any comment on the exact formula involving Legendre polynomials mentioned in GSW.

Comment: @coconut at the pole, you can replace $f(p^2/m^2)\to f(1)$, which can always be rescaled away. Away from the pole you have to refer to the detailed analysis in the reference, but the result is that the numerator is always a polynomial in the momenta (due to the representation theory of SU(2)).

Comment: @bolbteppa I am not familiar with any explicit formula, but I would not surprised one exists. After all, the Legendres are the eigenvectors of the angular momentum operators (cf spherical harmonics), so I would definitely expect them to appear when looking at the representation theory of SU(2).